# Unable to access joined table columns in Doctrine

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

Here is the schema of two tables that I am querying in doctrine.

I have two tables in my schema called taxonomy and lesson, which have a many to one relation [should really be one to one, but that's how it has been encoded]. My query is encoded in `TaxonomyTable.class.php` like this:

```
 $this->createQuery('t.*, l.lid')
      ->innerJoin('t.Lesson l')
      ->where('t.section = ?','specific_section');
```

The query executes as it should, the challenge really is accessing lesson lid.
Assuming the query is executed and stored in a variable `$TaxonomyResults` ;
From prior posts, I understand that it can be done like this:

```
foreach($TaxonomyResults as $TaxonomyResult)
{
   echo $TaxonomyResult->getLesson()->getLid();
}
```

But simply put, this does not work for me and I am not sure why. The error that renders across my screen is:

> 'Doctrine_Collection' does not have a method 'getLid'.

What do you think I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Could you paste your `schema.yml`?

Answer (score 2):

I can't see your schema.

I guess Taxonomy has a one to many relation with Lesson(Taxonomy is one).

So a Taxonomy object can have many Lessons,

and `$TaxonomyResult->getLesson()` should return Lesson objects (Doctrine_Collection), not a Lesson object.

You can get your lesson object like array:

```
$lessons = $TaxonomyResult->getLesson();

echo $lessons[0]->getLid();
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking but I wanted to see his schema.yml first

Comment: that should be technically correct...what I was missing out was that it is a one to many relation and returned a collection, hence a foreach  loop was required to iterate through the lesson object and access the specific methods